# LTspice Netlist Resistors have TOL in Netlist

Tags: ltspice, simulation, schematics, spice

Any resistor I place in the schematic has the letters "Tol" in its netlist. I've set all my settings to default value and it's still there. It typically doesn't get in the way unless I try to give a resistor a variable value (i.e. R={24*var}). Then the error log says I have an unknown variable "Tol".

Any ideas? I'm sure it has something to do with tolerance, but I can't make it go away.

[image: A lone resistor in a new schematic.]

```
* C:\Users\######\Documents\LTspiceXVII\Draft3.asc
R1 NC_01 NC_02 R Tol
.backanno
.end
```

Comment: Try closing LTspice, finding the `LTspiceXVII.ini` in your computer and move it elsewhere, then reopen LTspice to regenerate it. It should be in the `%AppData%` folder, or `%LocalAppData%`. Also, if `var` is a defined `.param` then you don't need to write `R=...`, just `{24*var}` instead of the default `R`.

Comment: Still, if the only problems you have are with the program, itself, a better place to ask these questions is the [LTspice group](https://groups.io/g/LTspice/).

Comment: Sure, I'll put it in that group. This is my first time posting, so I didn't know where to go exactly.